# Is it possible to make wiremock, record data in the same file?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, record, wiremock

I am new to wiremock. In the past couple of days I worked on it, and my configuration works fine, it does what i want it to do. But i want to enhance it in such a way that it is easier to use. 
By the way i am not stubbing manually, I am using the WireMockServer and created a configuration to start and record the requests and responses.

```
public static void mockServerStart(String proxyHost, int proxyPort,
        int mockPort) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // setting options required by wiremock
    MockHelper mockHelper = new MockHelper();
    mockHelper.setOptions();
    log.info(" [x] Root dir : " + mockHelper.wireMockRootDir);
    // create root directories if necessary
    createDirectories(mockHelper);
    // initialising wiremock
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.options()
            .port(mockPort).withRootDirectory(mockHelper.wireMockRootDir)
    // .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true))
    );
    wireMockServer.start();
    log.info(" [x] Starting mock server");
    log.info(" [x] Starting mock server recording");
    if (mockHelper.wireMockRecord) {
        // cleaning the previous stubs else it keeps on creating new files
        // without deleting the older ones
        cleanDirectories(mockHelper);
        wireMockServer.startRecording("http://" + proxyHost + ":"
                + proxyPort);
    }
}
```

It works fine, but the only thing is I need to turn a Boolean switch ON/OFF for it to work. In HoverFly we didn't need to do that. It will start recording if we just delete the previously recorded file. I want to have that functionality in wiremock.

So is it possible to make wiremock write in the same file, if it is then it will make my code easier.